# CSS: How to set text at bottom of line height

Tags: css

I have a div with `line-height: 3`. 
How can I position the text at bottom of the line height? Currently the text always anchors in the middle of the line-height.

```css
.test{
  background-color: yellow;
  line-height: 3
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
</div>
```

Comment: you should provide code

Comment: Line-height applies to all lines, even after line breaks, if you want this behavior to happen, but also need some extra spacing at the top you should use a wrapper div with an extra padding/margin.

Comment: `vertical-align: text-bottom;`

Comment: sorry but it's not working

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/79puq5ke/

Comment: You might use an extra wrapper for each word and vertical-align, but this is tricky,  breakable and not flexible: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNwKXy

Comment: sorry but text at bottom of line height not bottom of div

Answer (score 0):

You can't...line height affects all the text *and the space around it*. What you want is padding-top.

```css
.test {
  background-color: yellow;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
</div>
```